# how to embed js script into html

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to make an online calculator and made a js script my question is how can i add this script to my html i tried using script but it didn't do anything

```js
function motion1() {
var right=0;

var initvel = calc.initvel.value;
var finalvel = calc.finalvel.value;
var time = calc.time.value;
var accl = calc.accl.value;
var dist = calc.dist.value;


var complete="you have entered more than 3 values. Please leave two text box empty. Other two text box  will be calculated based on that";
var incomplete="Sorry! incomplete information";
var validinput="You have not entered numeric values!!";

if (isNaN(calc.initvel.value)) return alert(validinput);
if (isNaN(calc.finalvel.value)) return alert(validinput);
if (isNaN(calc.time.value)) return alert(validinput);
if (isNaN(calc.accl.value)) return alert(validinput);
if (isNaN(calc.dist.value)) return alert(validinput);

if(initvel!="" && finalvel!=""  && time!=""  && accl !="" ) return alert(complete);
if(initvel!="" && finalvel!=""  && time!=""  && accl !="" && dist !=""   ) return alert(complete);




if(initvel!="" && finalvel!=""  && time!=""  ){
accl=(finalvel-initvel)/time; 
calc.dist.value= initvel*time + .5*accl*time*time;
calc.accl.value=accl
right++;}

if(initvel!="" && finalvel!=""  && accl!=""  ){
time=(finalvel-initvel)/accl; 
calc.dist.value= initvel*time + .5*accl*time*time;
calc.time.value=time
right++;}

if(initvel!="" && time!=""  && accl!=""  ){
initvel=parseFloat(initvel);
calc.finalvel.value=initvel + (accl*time); 
calc.dist.value= initvel*time + .5*accl*time*time;
right++;}


if(finalvel!="" && time!=""  && accl!=""  ){
initvel=finalvel - (accl*time); 
calc.dist.value= initvel*time + .5*accl*time*time;
calc.initvel.value=initvel
right++;}

if(dist!="" && time!=""  && accl!=""  ){
initvel=(dist - .5*accl*time*time )/time; 
calc.finalvel.value= initvel*time + accl*time;
calc.initvel.value=initvel
right++;}

if(dist!="" && initvel!=""  && accl!=""  ){
finalvel=Math.pow(initvel*initvel +  2*dist*accl,.5); 
calc.time.value= (finalvel - initvel)/accl;
calc.finalvel.value=finalvel
right++;}

if(dist!="" && initvel!=""  && finalvel!=""  ){
accl=(finalvel*finalvel - initvel*initvel)/2/dist; 
calc.time.value= (finalvel - initvel)/accl;
calc.accl.value=accl
right++;}

if(dist!="" && finalvel!=""  && accl!=""  ){
initvel=Math.pow(finalvel*finalvel -  2*dist*accl,.5); 
calc.time.value= (finalvel - initvel)/accl;
calc.initvel.value=initvel
right++;}






if(!right) alert(incomplete); // Less than the required fields entered!

}
```

it is newton kinematics eq calculator if it is any helpful
it should look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDwsP.png)

so it would ask me for the value and it should be able to solve the other fields

Comment: put it in <script></script> tag inside your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you made is... that you don't call the script.
Currently you only have declared an JS-Function named `motion1`

To call it, only write "motion();" below your closed curly-bracket after the function.

BTW: Even if you call your Script, it won't work, because it has errors inside... if there are no global variable `calc` in your file. If your pasted script is only a `part of the page` and you've still have such an `calc` Object in your file, ignore this BTW-Comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes javascript belongs inbetween `<script> </script>` tags.

And then you bind actions to html elements like input boxes.

I would recommend starting with the basics and looking at some tutorials :)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Answer (score -1):

the better approach here you can download some calculator sample code from GitHub or any other platform and start debugging and modifying that code and try to add some more features to that calculator. Best of luck